# Java Load a script by default in ScriptEngine

Tags: java, javascript, java-8, scriptengine

Is there any way to include (or load) a external script to the script engine so that all the functions defined in the external script are available in the `engine.eval()` method ?

In our application we execute some java script code based on user inputs. When a user requests comes the application create a ScriptEngine instance and execute the appropriate javascript code based on the input parameters.

The problem here is there are some repeated functionality in the javascript. Consider an example :

**Scenario 1** : Calculate distance when user input is decimal latitudes and longitudes
-> Here I can simply calculate and return the distance.

**Scenario 2** : Calculate distance when user input is Degrees-Minutes-Seconds latitudes and longitudes.
-> Here convert the Degrees-Minutes-Seconds input into decimal latitudes and longitudes and then process same as Scenario 1.

As they are different scenario calculateDistance code is duplicated. 
So is there any way I could have an script containing reusable functions and load it when I create a ScriptEngine instance.

Note : I am using Java 8 along with the bundled Nashorn JavaScript Engine.

Any ideas and/or suggestion ?

Comment: will you clarify your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `load()` function in your javascript code ([doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/shell.html#sthref28)). Someting like :

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval("load('myScript.js');");
```

It's an easy way, but doesn't fit for deployment (relative paths always change, ressources access may be different in your IDE, Jar, war...).

I personnaly use a very simple interface to provide the script content, which then came from a ressource, external file, DB... and then use the result in `eval()`.

```
public interface ScriptLoader {
  public String getScriptContent(String relativePath);
}

ScriptLoader loader;
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(loader.getScriptContent('myScript.js'));
```

If your script source is not dynamic, it may also be usefull to keep your engine's instance cached, as the first cold start/parsing can be very long.